# ODATA Separating the SERVICE from the DATA

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have an app with 3 layers:
a) The service exposing web api with Odata
b) The Business Layer with all the business logic and the data access
c) The Model

If I use Odata queries directly in the service, accessing to the DB Context, everything works ok, My issues is....how can I achieve the same, but adding one layer in the middle?

MyService with Web API 2

```
[EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Individual> GetIndividuals()
    {

        IndividualBO bo = new IndividualBO();
        return bo.GetAllIndividuals();
    }
```

My Business Layer

```
public IQueryable<Individual> GetAllIndividuals()
    {
        using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
        {
            return context.Individuals;
        }
    }
```

This is not working......however if I remove the bo from the equation, everything works fine....any ideas?

Comment: Hi, Fede, What's the meaning of not working? Not return right result? return null?

Comment: using the working version.....it returns something like "Individual.json"....., that json can be saved, inspected, and consumed, however when I use the intermedate layer, it returns something like "individual\$something eq 'something'/"....that return cannot be saved, or opened or even consumed